# generate qr code with bacon/bacon-qr-code not working

Tags: laravel-5, qr-code

I tried using your sample code on both an existing image and a non-existing image .
Both case failed , and no image is generated on the latter.

## first trial:

```
$renderer = new \BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png();
$renderer->setHeight(256);
$renderer->setWidth(256);
$writer = new \BaconQrCode\Writer($renderer);
$writer->writeFile('Hello World!', 'qrcode.png');
```

i then thought i could just write string instead of writing into a file but when i echo i still don't get image

## 2nd trial :

`

```
         $renderer = new \BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png();

        $renderer->setHeight(256);

        $renderer->setWidth(256);

        $writer = new \BaconQrCode\Writer($renderer);

        $str= $writer->writeString('Hello World!');
       header('Content-Type:image/png');
      echo $str;`
```

i get the code below

`�PNG  IHDR�?1IDATx����n�0A'����kP!��؝9��������~������' �4�&�@�Hi M�    �4�&�@�Hi M�    �4�&�@�Hi M�    �4�&�@�Hi M� �4�&�@�Hi M�   �4����x�^���3:|������u�+W�_u?O��9�p�'��4�&�@�Hi#�W�Z'^��?m=������|�Hi M�    �4�6zpeպ�u�U�럾N?����<Hi M� �4�&Ҏ����@�'i M� �4�&�@�9�F�� ��<Hi M�   �4�&Ҏ�L[/�v?w�~�?�  @�Hi M� �4�6z0�|�?�>`�~A�|���!M�    �4�&�@�H�*���}��� M� �4�&�@�H����S_��������w'�� @�Hi M� �4�6b���u�����Ͽ�I�&�@�Hi M����~*��u�Lx�*<�^�����i M� �4�&�F�V�ǯz��ʴu��s�Us���Y�Q�0�&�@�Hi m�9�������U��w�|J�    �4�&�@�H18�)�ﾾs��0 M�   �4�&�@ڈ9���v���G�>E����̓M@�Hi M� ���\������<�������'i M�    �4�&�@��9�����=��)� �'i M�  �4�&�@ڑs�iv��?��?�'i M� �4�&�@�9�FO�{�j>P�3x�&�@�Hi M�98e�yչ����_�sw��>��4�&�@�Hi m����kv��OX��F�Hi M�  �4��5y�v� M�    �4�&�@�Hi M�    �4�&�@�Hi M�    �4�&�@�Hi M�    �4�&�@�Hi M� �4�&�@�Hi M�   ���mF�sE�}IEND�B`�`

What's the problem ?

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally decided to use the package simpleqr-code .
link here :https://www.simplesoftware.io/docs/simple-qrcode

Answer (score 7):

If you encode the output of the writeString to base64 you can then use it to show a base64 image in HTML.

```
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\ImageRenderer;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\ImagickImageBackEnd;
use BaconQrCode\Renderer\RendererStyle\RendererStyle;
use BaconQrCode\Writer;

$renderer = new ImageRenderer(
    new RendererStyle(200),
    new ImagickImageBackEnd()
);
$writer = new Writer($renderer);

$qr_image = base64_encode($writer->writeString($string));
```

And show it as an image like this.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, <?php echo $qr_image; ?> " />
```